# angularjs to output plain text instead of html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some text like this:

```
<span>My text</span>
```

I want to display without tags:

```
My text
```

I also don't want to apply the tags, I want to strip them. What's an easy way to do that?

Angular html:

```
<div>{{myText | htmlToPlaintext}}</div>
```

Comment: You have tagged this under AngularJS, so I assume you want to do display the text using AngularJS. If so, is this text in a model? Which html tag are you using to display the contents of the model?

Comment: @callmekatootie I created a filter based on the answer Abhishek gave.

Comment: I see that and his solution uses jQuery - You have tagged this under AngularJS and I have a feeling that you you can do it in AngularJS without using jQuery, if only you can give more information in your question - particularly where you wish to display the text in your view...

Comment: @callmekatootie I added an example of what I'm doing in angular

Answer (score 210, accepted):

[**jQuery is about 40 times SLOWER**, please do not use jQuery for that simple task.](http://jsperf.com/strip-html-jquery-vs-pure-js)

```
function htmlToPlaintext(text) {
  return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
}
```

usage :

```
var plain_text = htmlToPlaintext( your_html );
```

---

#### With angular.js :

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).
  filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
    };
  }
);
```

use :

```
<div>{{myText | htmlToPlaintext}}</div>
```

Comment: I actually prefer String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, ''). I've been using it for years without any issues.

Comment: jQuery is 40 times slower, but you still get 8000 ops/s, so not using jQuery for that reason is premature optimization.

Comment: @Blaise you are right, 8k ops/s is enough. But think of the whole picture. Is your app doing only that ? What about mobiles ? What about heavy applications ? Is there any browser compatibility issue involved ? What are the advantages of jQuery ? Is jQuery more readable ? Is jQuery easy to write ? Sometimes jQuery is good enough. But jQuery should not be used everywhere. Especially not here.

Comment: I would never add a jQuery dependency just to convert html to text, but if my project already used jQuery I would choose the jQuery solution because I consider a custom-written regular expression less readable, less tested and less reliable. Does your regular expression protect against [all possible forms of XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)?

Comment: @Blaise, if you add the text into the DOM with jQuery, you don't have to protect against XSS into **this** function. jQuery does it when added to the DOM. BTW, I'm really not sure which one is more readable.

Comment: using the DOM engine covers a lot more cases that this simple replace those not example:  some codes here &#146;  &#147; &#148;

Comment: You should probably add a null-check in there, or it will output "null": `return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : "";`

Comment: I'm wary of this solution. There's a number of circumstances where it will fail:

1. A less than sign '<' appearing in the text that's not a tag, i.e. <p>One < Two</p>. The string "< Two</p" will be deleted erroneously.

2. It won't convert character references like &amp; or more pertinently &lt;

Comment: You could shorten the regexp with a nongreedy search `/<.+?>/gm,` which looks a bit more intuitive, readable and also saves you a few characters.

Comment: This does not work if the html text is following.
`"<p><span style="color: rgb(34, 36, 38);text-align: left;float: none;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Some Text.</span><!--EndFragment--><br/><br/><br/></p>"`

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal what's wrong? it returns `Some Text.`, as I would expect it

Comment: How to show the preview ,instead of showing the plain text(it is working). but i need to show the preview like stack overflow shows while posting question or answer including images also

Comment: This will not work if there are close angle brackets in attributes or comments. For example, `<img src="file>.jpg" width="640" height="400" alt="image"><p><a href="http://example.com/path?var=>&utm_campaign=123">Hello</a><!-- sun > world -->World</p>`

Answer (score 21):

from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

> **angular.element**
>
> wraps a raw DOM element or HTML string as a jQuery element (If jQuery
>   is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in
>   subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite.")

So you simply could do:

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).
  filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return angular.element(text).text();
    }
  }
);
```

Usage:

```
<div>{{myText | htmlToPlaintext}}</div>
```

Comment: I would avoid this approach as well; might not take as long as full jQuery, but certainly much slower than accepted answer.

Comment: I suggest wrapping your text in an element otherwise a plain old string like "hi" will return an empty string `angular.element('<div>'+text+'</div>').text();`

Comment: if you're in the link function of a directive you can simply do element.text()    0.o

Comment: I prefer this solution to using a regex, at least in cases where speed isn't critical. It's more correct and will actually convert the html to plain text, extraneously less than signs, special entities and all.

Comment: How to show the preview ,instead of showing the plain text(it is working). but i need to show the preview like stack overflow shows while posting question or answer including images also

Comment: If your html have inline style then accepted answer fails, this way works fine :)

Comment: Kudos to this, using regex is quick but there will be edge cases where it fails. This is a simpler and safer way when performance is not critical. Thanks!

Comment: This will fail if `text` is not already wrapped in some HTML tag. So to be robust it should be more like: `return angular.element('<div>' + text + '</div>')`

Answer (score 4):

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.filter('htmlToPlaintext', function()
{
    return function(text)
    {
        return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
    };
});

<p>{{DetailblogList.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
```

Comment: add some formating an some insights to the code, that helps to generate better answers.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: There's a difference between a low-quality answer that should be voted down and a non-answer that should be deleted. Please see [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).

Comment: How to show the preview ,instead of showing the plain text(it is working). but i need to show the preview like stack overflow shows while posting question or answer including images also

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the built-in browser HTML strip for that instead of applying yourself a regexp. It is more secure since the ever green browser does the work for you.

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).
  filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return stripHtml(text);
    };
  }
);

var stripHtml = (function () {
  var tmpEl = $document[0].createElement("DIV");
  function strip(html) {
    if (!html) {
      return "";
    }
    tmpEl.innerHTML = html;
    return tmpEl.textContent || tmpEl.innerText || "";
  }
  return strip;
}());
```

The reason for wrapping it in an self-executing function is for reusing the element creation.

Comment: How to show the preview ,instead of showing the plain text(it is working). but i need to show the preview like stack overflow shows while posting question or answer including images also

Comment: changed $document[0] to document and it worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`<div ng-bind-html="myText"></div>`
No need to put into html {{}} interpolation tags like you did {{myText}}.

and don't forget to use ngSanitize in module like e.g.
`var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);`

and add its cdn dependency in index.html page https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-sanitize

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-bind-html, don't forget to inject $sanitize service into your module
Hope it helps

Answer (score -3):

Use ng-bind-html this is only proper and simplest way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more details for clarification. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -7):

Use this function like

```
 String.prototype.text=function(){
   return this ? String(this).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
 }

  "<span>My text</span>".text()
  output:
  My text
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zVMHK/32/)**

Comment: This is a jQuery-based solution. The question was about angularjs.

Comment: Rev The mark answer is javascript and if I did it using jquery what make it difference

Comment: Your solution is not compatible with OP's requirements. he already built his app on angularjs. jquery is a different framework.

Comment: +1 and I don't see here any jQuery... wtf? Another problem is @Abjo's method extends build in String prototype. That some developers choose to be angry about.