# Replace string in value from an JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON file which contains multiple `<br />` tags. The file is parsed using `JSON.parse(json)` into an object. Because I bind the data with AngularJS and ng-repeat I don't want that the strings have any HTML tags and replace it with a new line `\n`. How can I replace all tags? It seems to me that `replace()` only works with strings.

Thanks for your help!

**JSON example**

```
{
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "This<br />is<br />a<br />description."
}
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(json);
$scope.data = retrievedObject;
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    {{item.description}}
    {{item.description}}
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs to output plain text instead of html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngBindHtml` will let you keep keep the `<br>`s and render newlines in your HTML. It will automatically sanitize your input using `ngSanitize` to strip out any tags are aren't in its whitelist (you have to bring `ngSanitize` in as a dependency)...

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);
```

The view is as simple as...

```
<div ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
```

[**JsBin**](http://jsbin.com/yelegake/1/edit?html,js,output)

You can also use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` to tell `ngBindHtml` to blindly trust the HTML without sanitizing, but only do that if you can completely trust its content (i.e., not for things like user submitted comments, etc).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! I've tried `ng-bind-html` but I didn't know about `ngSanitize` and bringing it in as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace it before you parse the string

```
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(json.replace(/\<br \/\>/g, ''));
```

A better option would be  to parse the strings as HTML and extract the text without the tags, not using a regex before you insert them in the DOM

Comment: Thanks for your help. I forgot to mention that I want to replace the tags with a new line and edited my post while you answered my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to do what you're looking for. One with css where you replace the br's with 
\n and then in your css file give the element the white-space property of pre-wrap.

The other is angularish. Take a read of data-ng-bind-html. You'd be able to actualy have the br's outputted. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml You would have to run it through a filter of $sce so that it's trusted but your code would be as simple as:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <span data-ng-bind-html="item.description | trusted"></span>
    <span data-ng-bind-html="item.description | trusted"></span>
</div>
```

your filter for trusted would be this:

```
.filter("trusted", function($sce){
    return function(input){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
});
```