# Summernote content coming with html tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, summernote

I am new to summernote text editor. I am trying to get the proper content from the summernote textarea, which infact coming with html tags.
I tried

```
    <textarea class="summernote" id="summernote"  ng-model="blog.content" ></textarea>
```

in my html page and getting the textarea content with,

```
     $("#summernote").code();
```

it is fetching the content in 
   html tags. I want the content to be displayed without the html tags.

Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of searching , thought instead of trying that in getting summernote text editor value with plain text, why not try with the angular filter. So searched and got the filter which exactly does what I needed.

Here is the link which did my job.

[angularjs to output plain text instead of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html)

Answer (score 3):

Use val() to get all what entered in textarea or text, So :

```
var content = $("#summernote").val()
```

Comment: You can use a fade action

Comment: for 10 millisecond then use this

Answer (score 3):

in laravel, simple use

```
{!! $product->small_description !!}
```

instread of
{{! $product->small_description !}}

in blade file where you want to fetch the data

Answer (score 2):

Use $().text() method to get plain text.

```
$("<div />").html($("#summernote").code()).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, "fixed" it by using version 0.6.16 instead of the current stable version 0.7. HTML is rendering fine now without extra js code.

Comment: Oh thank you! This fixed my issue! I've been tearing my hair for about an hour.