# How to display HTML from model as HTML, not plain text

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and making a todo app. Creating a todo uses a wysiwyg editor ([textAngular](http://textangular.com/)). It looks like this:

[image: create todo with wysiwyg]

This works properly and gets saved as html to ng-model named `todo.description`. But when displaying this todo, the html from the description is displayed as plain text. Like so:

[image: Display todo HTML as plain text]

The description is just bound to the model

```
<p class="text-muted">{{todo.description}}</p>
```

I think this can be done very simple but I didn't find a solution. I tried the `xmp` tag, but that's not what I'm looking for.

How can I make the description display HTML and not text?

Comment: probably this string is escaped. So you need to put raw text

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html

Comment: Question is basically duplicate indeed. But the answer given by @Vishnu is different and beter. I consider this question not having added value, but the answer does.

Comment: @Tonny seems to be two different questions. In the mentioned links, all html tag will be ignored and model will be rendered as plain text without style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<p class="text-muted" ng-bind-html="todo.description"></p>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to display your html code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.html = '<b>Test</b><u>Test</u>&lt;HTML';
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span ng-bind-html="html"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `$trustAsHTML` filter of `$sce` (Strict contextual escaping)