# How to convert html tags to text in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Code

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.htmlcode" />
$scope.data={};
```

In the above html page contains text field. when i enter html content in that text field like`<div> <h1> welcome </h1> </div>`, that content i want to convert to text otherwise that will be calling to mvc `controller` like using `$http` services.

```
eg:- $http.post("/controller/action?data="+$scope.data)
```

Comment: Simply do: var yourDataToSend = angular.element('<div/>').html($scope.data).text();

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html

Comment: Hi Jaydeep. Your Code also getting plain text, but i want convert entire text present in textfield . i enter text like <div>hello</div> . Your answer get hello text only

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to remove the html from the string in **data.htmlcode**? This code might help you

```
function stripHTML(s) {
   var holder = document.createElement('div');
   holder.innerHTML = s;
   return holder.innerText;
}


<div> <h1> welcome </h1> </div>
```

//would simply print out **welcome**

If however, you are trying to escape the html string, like return

```
&lt;div&gt; &lt;h1&gt; welcome &lt;/h1&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
```

This function might help you then

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
   var holder = document.createElement('div');
   holder.innerText = s;
   return holder.innerHTML;
}
```