# Retrieve html content that stored in mysql and display it as html in page

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

I have successfully return JSON data using PHP and delivered to my user's browser successfully. The return JSON is like this.

```
{
 "html":"<div class='sampleClass'><span>Test Site</span></div>"
}
```

Here is my angular js code

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    var successCallBack = function(response){
            $scope.test=response.data.records;
    }
    var errorCallBack = function(response){
        $scope.error = response.data;
    }
    $scope.getAll = function(){
        $http.get("read_list.php").then(successCallBack,errorCallBack);

    }
});
```

And here is how I display the data

```
<tbody ng-init="getAll()">
    <tr ng-repeat="d in test">
        <td>{{ d.html }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I want to achieve is to ouptut the above JSON like this

**Test Site**

just the Test Site only, not the whole html return.

I do some research about here but still I have no luck. I hope someone will help me with this.

BTW, I'm using angular js here to display the data.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you generate DOM elements through server side when you can do it inside your AngularJS code?

Comment: Is the above question not possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it. Is your JSON data, as shown, in your php program in your server, or has it been delivered to your user's browser already?

Comment: Well... you can add HTML code like this using PHP for example with an echo: 'echo "<div class='sampleClass'><span>Test Site</span></div>"', but I don't know if it's possible in any other way.

Comment: @O.Jones I have edited the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Please add essential information to your question: **How** do you currently use the JSON from the response in your HTML document (show your Javascript code) ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany I already add the javascript code in my question. Thanks

Comment: THis should help clear html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html