# Angular way to convert HTML-string to text string

Tags: angular

Currently I'm using

```
htmlToText(html: string) {
    const tmp = document.createElement('DIV');
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || '';
}
```

for the task. What's the Angular way of doing that? Or is it perfectly fine to do like that? Can directly accessing `document` like that lead to problems, e.g. with mobile apps?

Note: There's an [AngularJS related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html), but I'm looking for an Angular2+ anwer. Plus I'm not sure whether the regex from that accepted answer is the way to go?

Comment: after 6 years more experience looking back at this question I'd say: It's fine like this. why would I create a pipe if it's for a one time usage? from an interop perspective I don't see problems. and `tmp` should be garbage collected, so no problem there either.

Answer (score 4):

Create a pipe

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    @Pipe({name: 'htmlToPlaintext'})
    export class HtmlToPlaintextPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: string): string {
        return value? value.replace(/]+>/gm, '') : '';
      }
    }
```

and use this pipe in your template

```
    {{yourAttribute | htmlToPlaintext}}
```

In Angular, you should not modify the dom directly from your component. It should always be possible to use the template to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4):

**you should create a pipe like this**:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'htmlToPlaintext'
})
export class HtmlToPlaintextPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): string {
        const temp = document.createElement('div');
        temp.innerHTML = value;
        return temp.textContent || temp.innerText || '';
    }
}
```

and use this pipe like this:

```
{{htmlCode | htmlToPlaintext}}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain that how your answer is different from other answers of this page?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is escape these characters, then you archive what you want:

```
" replace with &quot;
& replace with &amp;
< replace with &lt;
> replace with &gt;
```

[more about escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

XML / HTML / XHTML or any SGML derivat will not parse these characters as what they intended for.

Answer (score 0):

To render html as a string in Angular 2+, we can use the innerHTML property. For example:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Or, have a look at this converter: https://www.npmjs.com/package//html-to-text

More information: [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 0):

@bersling I had a similar situation but I use a template variable to achieve the same.

```
      <p #desc
        class="[ hit hit__description ]"
        [innerHTML]="hit.shortText"
        [matTooltip]="desc.innerText"
        [matTooltipDisabled]="desc.innerText.length < 140"
      ></p>
```