# mailto protocol on a link opens with HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using the following code in angular JS template to open outlook with some fields pre filled.

```
<a href="mailto:{{item.caseOwner}}?subject= Case {{item.caseNumber}}">OWNER</a>
```

where -

```
item.caseOwner = abc@xyz.com;
```

This works fine when `item.caseOwner` is a string. But in some scenarios, it comes wrapped in an HTML tag for the highlighting purpose.

```
item.caseOwner = <span class"highlight">abc@xyz.com<span>;
```

In this case the outlook opens up with HTML tags and it makes no meaning. Is there a way to extract the string inside the `<span></span>` before the user clicks the link ?

Comment: Yes, you could create an onclick event in your A tag and do some cleaning. This may works (to be tested).

Can't you do the highlighting in some other way ? There's no reason to have html tags inside html tags !

Comment: Maybe the [npm striptags package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags) is helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs to output plain text instead of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom filter to cleanup `item.caseOwner`.

```
<a href="mailto:{{item.caseOwner | asEmail }}?subject= Case {{item.caseNumber}}">OWNER</a>
```

For cleaning up span tags, a search-replace can be implemented like so.

```
function asEmailFn(emailAddressOrMarkup) {
    return emailAddressOrMarkup
        .replace(/<[\/]*?span.*?>/g, '');
}

angular.module('App', [])
.filter('asEmail', function() {
  return asEmailFn;
})
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'asEmail', function($scope, asEmail) {
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Oluwefemi. I have done it in a bit different way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it.

In the main parent controller of application i.e. alias `home`

```
home.stripOffHTML = function(itemString){
    let localString = itemString;
    if(localString){
      return localString.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
    }
};
```

In the HTML code:

```
<a href="mailto:{{home.stripOffHTML(item.caseOwner)}}?subject=Case {{item.caseNumber}}">OWNER</a>
```